# Do I need Chocolatey in Node.js for web development?

Tags: node.js, chocolatey

During my Node installation, I was asked if I wanted to install Chocolatey. I am only interested in web development.

Do I need Chocolatey for web development?

Answer (score 11):

Chocolatey is a Windows Package Manager, it manages packages.

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/#what-is-chocolatey

You don't *need* Chocolatey in order to do web development.  Having Chocolatey makes the automated installation and updating of the applications on your machine easier.

By itself, Chocolatey doesn't do anything with regard to updating the underlying operating system.  I believe that you may be referring to an issue with a version of Node which included a Boxstarter script, which installed a number of Chocolatey packages, which also had the side effect of performing a series of Windows Updates during the installation.  This was an unfortunate situation, but I believe it has been resolved.

Comment: [Potential description](https://github.com/chocolatey/boxstarter/issues/371) of the weird Boxstarter thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I waited for around 10-15 mins then I got bored and pressed "m" key in keyboard (Idk why lol) and it finishes with no warning or errors. Try it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).